# My second button in andiroid studio dosenot work, even i set a diffrent methods in particular button's onclick properties

Tags: android

This is My main activity program :

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 private static ImageView im1;
 private static Button btm,btm2;
private int current_image_index;
int[] images={R.mipmap.mylogo,R.mipmap.picasa,R.mipmap.twitter};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void onclk(View v)
{
  im1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    btm=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    btm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            current_image_index++;
            current_image_index = current_image_index % (images.length);
            im1.setImageResource(images[current_image_index]);
        }
    });
}
public void onclk2(View v)
{
    im1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    btm2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

    btm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            current_image_index--;
            current_image_index = current_image_index % (images.length);
            im1.setImageResource(images[current_image_index]);
        }
    });
}
}
```

I desighned two button named as forwardbutton and backward button, i set an onclick property for each buttons, first btton onclik(), second button onclk2() function.....
But while running the app backward button doesnot works

Comment: in your code..you call clicklistner with same name. please replace it with btm2.setonclicklistner()

Comment: you should reduce your example to a minimum, so it's easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
btm2.setOnClickListener
```

insted of

`btm.setOnClickListener`

in second function

and the complete code is

```
    public void onclk2(View v)
{
    im1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    btm2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);


    btm2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            current_image_index--;
            current_image_index = current_image_index % (images.length);
            im1.setImageResource(images[current_image_index]);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code with your Code:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 private static ImageView im1;
 private static Button btm,btm2;
private int current_image_index;
int[] images={R.mipmap.mylogo,R.mipmap.picasa,R.mipmap.twitter};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void onclk(View v)
{
  im1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    btm=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    btm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            current_image_index++;
            current_image_index = current_image_index % (images.length);
            im1.setImageResource(images[current_image_index]);
        }
    });
}
public void onclk2(View v)
{
    im1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    btm2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

    // Your Error Was Here/in Below Line
    btm2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            current_image_index--;
            current_image_index = current_image_index % (images.length);
            im1.setImageResource(images[current_image_index]);
        }
    });
}
}
public void onclk2(View v)
{
    im1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    btm2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

    btm2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            current_image_index--;
            current_image_index = current_image_index % (images.length);
            im1.setImageResource(images[current_image_index]);
        }
    });
}
```

Hope this will helps...(: